# Sequence of 1, -1 that makes the sum convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers that converge to $0$.

Let $\epsilon_1 = \pm 1, \epsilon_2 = \pm 1,...$.

Then, does there exist such {$\epsilon_n$}'s such that $\sum \epsilon_n z_n$ converges?

$\\$
$\\$
$\\$

Actually, I found this problem in a book, but can't seem to remember the book's name. Does anyone know it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem $54$ in "Coffee Time in Memphis," by Béla Bollobás.  The answer is in the affirmative, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :)